# Extra router in my list of network devices?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I'm running Windows 7, when I go to see the list of the devices on my network, 2 routers show up. One is mine, the other one is definitely not...it's got a mac address I don't have in the list of mac addresses my router knows, but doesn't have an IP address (as far as I can see). Any ideas why this would happen? Is Windows getting confused by my neighbor's router or something?

Comment: Assuming you're looking at the DHCP list, in which case static IP addresses usually won't show up.  I'd also like to point out that it's *possible* that your router is compromised, and your best bet would be to block/blacklist the unknown MAC address.

Comment: I use DHCP, but assign specific IPs to most of my devices. The odd MAC address out isn't in that list, nor is it in my whitelist of allowed wireless MAC addresses. My router also doesn't show that MAC in the list of connected devices.

Comment: Odd, now it's gone. This has happened before, but this is the first time (I think) that I've seen a MAC address when I look at the device properties. I'll keep an eye out for more information. Edit: Weird, if I refresh, the odd one out is the first thing that shows up in the list. Is windows just confused by something? :/